# PHP GD: Font size depending on image size

Tags: php, gd

I have interesting problem.

I need to generate an image with PHP GD implementation however font size needs to by dynamic. I need it to be 7% of the current image size. Does anybody has any suggestion how my approach should look like?

Comment: Where are you having trouble? What have you tried? Seems basic enough. Find the image's height and multiple by .07.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just taking imagesy(), multiply by 0.07, and then set the image font size ? What's wrong with that simple approach ?

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks. I'm quite new to image manipulation with PHP, just started to learn new functions.